# How is returning a variable "let" inside a function allowed in rust?

Tags: rust, dangling-pointer

[This example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b96201c4081121965ad3dc85ecc22476) compiles and returns the "expected" output. But is this not a dangling pointer scenario? If so, how come the rust compiler allows this?

```
use serde_json::{Value, json};
use std::io::Result;

fn main(){
    println!("{:#?}", test_json_lifetime());
}

fn test_json_lifetime() -> Result<(Value)> {                            
    let j = json!({ "name" : "test" }); 
    Ok(j)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are thinking that `j` is allocated on the stack frame of `test_json_lifetime()` (that memory gets deallocated at the end of the function when the stack unwinds), and we return a reference to `j` (which would result in a dangling pointer).

In this case, you are correct that `j` gets allocated on the stack, however when we return `Ok(j)` we do not return a reference to `j`, rather we copy `j` to the space for the `Result<(Value)>` that was allocated on `main()`'s stack frame before the function call to `test_json_lifetime()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [this section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#return-values-and-scope).

```
fn main() {
let s1 = gives_ownership();         // gives_ownership moves its return
                                    // value into s1

let s2 = String::from("hello");     // s2 comes into scope

let s3 = takes_and_gives_back(s2);  // s2 is moved into
                                    // takes_and_gives_back, which also
                                    // moves its return value into s3
} 

// Here, s3 goes out of scope and is dropped. s2 goes out of scope but was
// moved, so nothing happens. s1 goes out of scope and is dropped.

fn gives_ownership() -> String {             // gives_ownership will move its
                                             // return value into the function
                                             // that calls it

    let some_string = String::from("hello"); // some_string comes into scope

    some_string                              // some_string is returned and
                                             // moves out to the calling
                                             // function
}
```